# Merge nested Maps with specified key

Tags: java, java-stream

I have a `Map` as below,

```
Map<String, Map<String, String>> dateFormatsMap;

Map<String,String> m1 = Map.of("A","DD", "B", "MM", "C","YY");
Map<String,String> m2 = Map.of("A","DD-MM", "X", "MM", "C","YYYY");
Map<String,String> m3 = Map.of("X","DD", "Y", "MM", "C","YY");

dateFormatsMap = Map.of("P2",m2,"P1",m1, "p3",m3);
```

This map is populated from DB and has project-wise data.

What I want is to get merged `Map` of a specific project and one default project and **in case of a duplicate, I want to keep values of a specified project.**

I tried below code,

```
private static Map<String, String> getFormats(String project) {
    Set<String> projects = Set.of("P1", project);   //e.g "P1" as default project
    return dateFormatsMap.entrySet().stream()
            .filter(e->projects.contains(e.getKey()))
            .flatMap(e->e.getValue().entrySet().stream())
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue,
                    (o,n)->o));
}
```

I call this method as,

```
getFormats("P2");
```

But this gives the varying results having values sometimes from "P1" and sometimes from "P1".

> {A=DD, B=MM, C=YY, X=MM}
>
> {A=DD-MM, B=MM, C=YYYY, X=MM}

I need to have a fixed result as,

> {A=DD-MM, B=MM, C=YYYY, X=MM}

You can check [ideone](https://ideone.com/41Djfi)

I hope, I have detailed the question. I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to deal with this without using `Stream`s, you could also seek is using `putAll` -

```
private static Map<String, String> getFormats(String project) {
    Map<String, String> baseProjFormats = dateFormatsMap.get("P1");
    Map<String, String> currentProjFormats = dateFormatsMap.getOrDefault(project, Collections.emptyMap());
    baseProjFormats.putAll(currentProjFormats);
    return baseProjFormats;
}
```

Comment: as `Map.of` used in OP returns an `ImmutableCollections.Map` this throws an `UnsupportedOperationException`.

Comment: This seems much better. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I added all from the default project which are not in the specific project map and afterwards added everything from the specific project map:

```
 private static Map<String, String> getMyFormats(String project) {
    String defaultProject = "P1";
    Map<String, String> specificMap = dateFormatsMap.get(project);

    Map<String, String> collect = dateFormatsMap.get(defaultProject).entrySet().stream()
               .filter(e -> !specificMap.containsKey(e.getKey()))
               .collect(toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue));

    collect.putAll(specificMap);
    return collect;
 }
```

or using `collectingAndThen`:

```
private static Map<String, String> getFormats(String project) {
    String defaultProject = "P1";
    Map<String, String> collect = dateFormatsMap.get(defaultProject).entrySet().stream()
                .filter(e -> !dateFormatsMap.get(project).containsKey(e.getKey()))
                .collect(collectingAndThen(
                        toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue),
                        map -> {
                            map.putAll(dateFormatsMap.get(project));
                            return map;
                        })
                );    
   return collect;
}
```

Comment: This doesn’t look better than the one I posted. +1 for your efforts. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution. Created two maps and then merged  as below,

```
 private static Map<String, String> getFormats(String project) {
    Map<String, String> baseProjFormats = dateFormatsMap.get("P1");
    Map<String, String> currentProjFormats = dateFormatsMap.get(project);

    return Stream.of(baseProjFormats, currentProjFormats)
            .flatMap(e -> e.entrySet().stream())
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue,
                    (o, n) -> n));
 }
```

I would welcome any better solution.

Comment: I don't get the part, where your existing solution doesn't work, but this does? What is the input provided as `project`?

Comment: in existing solution, I was streaming over whole map and filtering the project. I was using (old, new) to handle duplicated. But this old,new values would be different in runs. You can run the ideone that I provided multiple times, you will see the different results.

Answer (score 0):

I'm just going to be the guy who doesn't use streams:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Map<String, String> defaultMap = Map.of("A", "DD", "B", "MM", "C", "YY");
    Map<String, String> mapToMerge = Map.of("A", "DD-MM", "X", "MM", "C", "YYYY");

    // Do the magic
    Map<String, String> result = new HashMap<String, String>();
    result.putAll(mapToMerge);

    for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : defaultMap.entrySet())
        if (!result.containsKey(entry.getKey()))
            result.put(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());

    // Print results
    result.entrySet().stream().forEach(System.out::println);
}
```